# Find days, hours and minutes to a time on certain days

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I am fairly new to java development and have come accross a problem i need help with.

I need to find out the days(if applicable), hours and minutes until 8.30 am. However, as this is a "countdown to school" the code has to know that if the next 8.30 am is on saturday or sunday, it should show the time until monday 8.30AM. Again, sorry if that does not make to much sense. So the logical way i would go about approaching this is by:

1. Working out whether tomorrow is either monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday or friday.
2. If it is, work out the number of hours and minutes until 8.30am tomorrow and convert that into 2 strings (hours and minutes)
3. Else, work out the days, hours and minutes until monday 8.30 am and convert them to strings(days, hours and minutes)

   ```
   Date dt = new Date();
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   c.setTime(dt);
   c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
   c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
   c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
   dt = c.getTime();
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
   String datetommorow = dateFormat.format(dt);
   int date22 = Integer.parseInt(datetommorow);
   int date33 = date22 + 1;
   Integer.toString(date33);
   ```

As you can see from this attempt i am struggling with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need any more infomation **do not hesitate to ask**

Comment: Just to give you the answer to your point 1)                       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
  Date tomorrow = cal.getTime();
  System.out.println(sdf.format(tomorrow));                                   This should give your tommorows day

Comment: Ok thanks! But i don't even know where to start with the rest of my question! That is why i posted this question! Do you have any idea, because this has stumped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentDay = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        Calendar school = Calendar.getInstance();
        school.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

        if (currentDay == Calendar.SATURDAY)
        {
            school.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        else if (currentDay == Calendar.FRIDAY)
        {
            school.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);
        }

        school.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        school.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        long millisLeft = school.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
        long hoursLeft = millisLeft / (60 * 60 * 1000);
        long minutesLeft =  (millisLeft % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. All i needed to do to this was this: String timeleft = Long.toString(hoursLeft) + "Hours " + Long.toString(hoursLeft) + "Minutes";

Comment: I'm pretty sure the day of the week logic is wrong, like if it's before 8:30 you will get a bad result, but you can fix that.

Comment: Caution: this answer ignores the crucial issue of time zone. By ignoring time zone, you get the JVM's default time zone. That time zone may vary from time to time and from computer to computer.

Comment: @BasilBourque His question concerns Android, which means Calendar.getInstance() gets the current local time.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        System.out.println("Tommorow is : " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

        Calendar future = Calendar.getInstance(); //future time
        future.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        future.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8); // Set hours to 8'O clock
        future.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); //get current time
        long hoursDiff = (future.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis())/(60 * 60 * 1000);
        long minDiff = (future.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis())/(60 * 1000);
        System.out.println("Hours left : " + hoursDiff);
        System.out.println("Minutes left : " + minDiff);
```

Comment: you can use parts of it and build upon your logic, this is just to give you a reference as to how to find a future date or how to find difference between two dates

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Joda-Time for Android. Additionally, DateFormat is inherently unsafe in multithreaded environments and the Date API is ugly and broken in general (at least for <=1.7 afaik)